# Discord bot check if user is admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi i'm new to python coding with discord and I have tried to make a command that tells the user if they are a admin or not but well... its not working in the slightest

```
    @client.command(name="whoami",description="who are you?")
async def whoami():
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if context.message.author.mention == discord.Permissions.administrator:
        msg = "You're an admin {0.author.mention}".format(message)  
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
    else:
        msg = "You're an average joe {0.author.mention}".format(message)  
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

I then get this when I try to type whoami

```
Ignoring exception in command whoami
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in whoami
NameError: name 'message' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'message' is not defined
```

Comment: What not working? Is there an exception?

Comment: Where does `message` come from ?

Comment: just added what it spits out when I try and activate the command

Comment: what do you mean?  Sorry i'm very new if it is obvious

Comment: Try adding _context_ to your first if statement
`if context.message.author == client.user:`

Comment: I added the `context.` to `messge.author` and it didnt fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
@client.command(name="whoami",description="who are you?")
async def whoami():
```

to

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def whoami(ctx):
```

Then you can use `ctx` to get all kinds of stuff like the user that wrote it, the message contents and so on

To see if a `User` is an administrator do
`if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator:` which should return `True` if the user is an an Administator

Your code should look like this:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

client = Bot(description="My Cool Bot", command_prefix="!", pm_help = False, )
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot is ready!")
  return await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='My bot'))

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def whoami(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator:
        msg = "You're an admin {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)  
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
    else:
        msg = "You're an average joe {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)  
        await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
client.run('Your_Bot_Token')
```

Comment: This answer shoudl be updated: 
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'server_permissions'

Comment: its 'guild_permissions' now

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`has_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions) [check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.check) to see if a user has the [`administrator`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Permissions.administrator) privilege.

We can then handle the error that failing that check will throw in order to send a failure message.

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, has_permissions, CheckFailure

client = Bot("!")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def whoami(ctx):
    msg = "You're an admin {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention)  
    await ctx.send(msg)

@whoami.error
async def whoami_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
        msg = "You're an average joe {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention)  
        await ctx.send(msg)
```

Comment: In the error handler, it seems the arguments are swapped. It must say:
async def whoami_error(ctx, error):

Comment: @PepeOchoa This is an old answer, the positions was swapped as a breaking change in 1.0  I've updated the code

Answer (score 6):

If `message.author.server_permissions.administrator` doesn't work.

Change it to `message.author.guild_permissions.administrator`

Or try `message.author.top_role.permissions.administrator`, this will return you a bool.

One thing is, normally the server owner sets the administrator to the server top role, so this will work most of the time. But if they don't, the third sol won't work.