# How to check if someone is administrator [Discord bot in Python]

Tags: python, discord

As the title says, I can't check if someone is administrator. I tried the following code :

```
if message.content.startswith("!add"):
    if discord.Member.server_permissions == "administrator" :
        messagePart = message.content.partition(" ")
        places.append(messagePart[2])
        para = discord.Embed(title="List of every landing site", description=show())
        await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=para)
    else :
        return
```

But I also tried this :

```
if message.content.startswith("!add"):
    if message.author.server_permissions.administrator == True:
        messagePart = message.content.partition(" ")
        places.append(messagePart[2])
        para = discord.Embed(title="List of every landing site", description=show())
        await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=para)
    else :
        return
```

Nothing worked. Can you help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord bot check if user is admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240878/discord-bot-check-if-user-is-admin)

Comment: I think that second one should work.  Could you try printing `message.author.server_permissions.administrator`?

Answer (score 0):

If  `message.author.server_permissions.administrator` doesn't work.

Change it to `message.author.guild_permissions.administrator`

Or try `message.author.top_role.permissions.administrator`, this will return you a bool.

One thing is, normally the server owner sets the administrator to the server top role, so this will work most of the time. But if they don't, the third sol won't work.