# How would I get my bot to return a message saying "Permission Denied, you do not have sufficient permissions."

Tags: python, discord.py

In my code here, if the user that executes one of these commands I would like my bot to message in the same channel "You do not have sufficient permissions. "

I have already tried this and it doesn't work.

```
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.kick_members:
        await client.kick
        embed = discord.Embed(title="User Kicked!",
                              description="**{0}** kicked by **{1}**!".format(member, ctx.message.author),
                              color=discord.Colour.green())
        await client.say(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Permission Denied.", description="You don't have permission to use this command.",
                              color=discord.Colour.red())
        await client.say(embed=embed)
```

I added the `else:` onto it and whatever is below the `else` doesn't work.

````
client = Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)
commands = discord.ext.commands

@client.command(name='kick', pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.kick_members:
        await client.kick
        embed = discord.Embed(title="User Kicked!",
                              description="**{0}** kicked by **{1}**!".format(member, ctx.message.author),
                              color=discord.Colour.green())
        await client.say(embed=embed)```

I expect my bot (client) to say in the same channel the command was sent in to say "You do not have sufficient permissions."
````

Comment: You need to use an error handler to do things if the check fails.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51246799/6779307

Comment: Thanks @PatrickHaugh, life saver. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `permissions_for` to check for permissions without raising an exception. In your case it would look something like `ctx.channel.permissions_for(ctx.author).kick_members`.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel.permissions_for