# Discord py how to make administrators command?

Tags: discord, discord.py

How do I create commands that are only available to administrators in discord py?

```
async def 청소(ctx, amout:int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amout)
    print('한 유저가 청소를 했습니다.')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord bot check if user is admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240878/discord-bot-check-if-user-is-admin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@commands.has_permissions()`. `commands.errors.MissingPermissions` is called when someone doesn't have permissions to run a command. To make an error message pop up, use the `on_command_error` event like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send('You are missing permissions to run this command!')
```

Anyways, the final code is:

```py
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.command()
async def 청소(ctx, amount:int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    print('한 유저가 청소를 했습니다.')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```py
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount = 100):  #100 will be the default amount purged
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount + 1)
        await ctx.send(f'**{amount}** message(s) deleted.')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Sorry, You are not an administrator.')
```